# How stop Outlook alternative greeting pop-up, or close it automatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook

Only 1 user in my company gets a pop-up every time she get's an email and she has her auto replies turned on.  I can't post an image, but if you go to imgur, and add forward slash and 'xooZR8D' without the quotes, you will see the popup.  The title of the popup is Microsoft Outlook and the body of the popup is: Your IMAP server wants to alert you to the following: [150] Your alternate greeting is currently being used.

Ideally, I'd like to know how to turn this off.  Alternatively, does anyone have code for a .Net program (preferably VB, C# would be my second choice) to scan open windows and close the desired one?  When I scanned for open processes and found one that had the title I wanted to close, calling process.close or process.closeMainWindow did nothing, and process.Kill closed the window and the Outlook application, which I don't want.  TIA

Comment: This seems a rather convoluted solution to a non-issue.  That popup with be getting driven by email and/or outlook account settings.  Wouldn't the better idea to be fix the problem at the source?

Comment: @Hursey, I'd love to fix it at the source, I just haven't found the settings that will stop the pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, although it doesn't get to the root of the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClosePopupsCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer2.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void DeleteOutlookPopups()
        {
            timer2.Enabled = false;
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Microsoft Outlook");
            if (hWnd != null)
            {
                if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
                {
                    bool ret = CloseWindow(hWnd);
                }
            }
            timer2.Enabled = true;
        }

        static bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            return true;
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteOutlookPopups();
        }
    }
}
```